# Analytically derive n-spherical coordinates conversions from cartesian coordinates

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I'm finding it difficult to find any non-geometrical derivation of coordinate conversions from cartisan to spherical.

I can understand the derivations geometrically, because I can visualize the construction. However, if I would want to find n-spherical coordinates conversions, how would I do so?

In other words, how do I go from 2D:

\begin{align} x & =r\cos\theta \\[6pt]
y & =r\sin\theta \\[6pt]
\end{align}

to 3D:

\begin{align} 
z & =r\cos\theta \\[6pt]
y & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\[6pt]
x & =r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\[6pt]
\end{align}

to 4D:

\begin{align}
w & =r\cos\theta \\[6pt]
z & =r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\[6pt]
y & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi \\[6pt]
x & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\psi \\[6pt]
\end{align}

and etc..

---

Ok, I can see a pattern to emerge and can guess that 5D is:

\begin{align}
v & =r\cos\theta \\[6pt]
w & =r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\[6pt]
z & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi\cos\psi \\[6pt]
y & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi\sin\delta \\[6pt]
x & =r\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi\cos\delta \\[6pt]
\end{align}

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that if the point $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ lies on the sphere of radius $r$, then
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=r^2.$$
Now $x_1$ ranges from $-r$ to $r$, so we can let $x_1 = r\cos\theta_1$ for $\theta_1\in[0,\pi]$. Then
$$\begin{align}
x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2&=r^2-x_1^2\\
&=(r\sin\theta_1)^2,
\end{align}$$
so $(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ lies on a sphere of radius $r\sin\theta_1$. (This is sensible because $\sin\theta_1\ge0$ when $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.) Then we continue to do the same thing:
$$x_2=(r\sin\theta_1)\cos\theta_2,$$
$$\begin{align}
x_3+\cdots+x_n&=(r\sin\theta_1)^2-x_2^2\\
&=(r\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)^2,
\end{align}$$
$$x_3=(r\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)\cos\theta_3,$$
$$\vdots$$
You have to be a little careful when you get down to $x_{n-1}$. Either set the range of $\theta_{n-1}$ to $[0,2\pi]$ to cover the full circle in two dimensions, or let $x_n=\pm r\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\cdots\sin\theta_{n-1}$ because the circle in one dimension contains *two* points.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty cool! I can see how it all works now. Thanks!